# 'Act against' vs 'act against it'

Tags: grammar, pronouns, formal-language, formality

Are both options correct and formal? If so, which one is preferable?

> 1: It would happen if we don't act against **it**

> 2: It would happen if we don't act against

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Both are incorrect

1. It would happen if we don't act against it

> It will happen if we don't act against it

2. It would happen if we don't act against

> It will happen if we don't act.

---

**We use will:**

> to express beliefs about the present or future
> to talk about what people want to do or are willing to do
> to make promises, offers and requests.

**would is the past tense form of will**. Because it is a past tense, it is used:

> to talk about the past
> to talk about hypotheses (when we imagine something)
> for politeness.

> What would happen if we don't act? (hypothesis)

---

Ref [British Council](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/english-grammar-reference/will-and-would)

Comment: There's nothing actually incorrect in this answer., but it doesn't address the specific issue OP asked about (whether just ***against*** without ***it*** is syntactically valid), except indirectly by implication (since you didn't actually include ***against*** without ***it*** in your "revised" versions, which superficially seem only intended to indicate that OP should have used ***will*** rather than ***would***).

Comment: "If we don't take action" sounds more idiomatic to me than "if we don't act", in contemporary UK or US usage. Maybe "act" has too many other meanings, or "take action" sounds more forceful.

Comment: @stuart-F Agree that is the slogan often heard. But the postee is not incorrrect in using act.

Comment: @FumbleFingers here is nothing actually incorrect in this comment. I should have pointed out several problems I could have ripped the post to shreds and jumped all over it. Instead I rectified the tense and explained why. Then removed unnecessary appendages and left it at that. Just think of the length of my reply to correct and explain more points. All of which are in point of fact relatively trivial in comparison to the misuse of tense. But yes I have to agree, technically you are quite correct in your comment.

Comment: Yeah - I assume both of us would much rather see ***will** happen IF we **don't...*** or ***would** happen IF we **didn't***. But I've spent the last couple of decades gradually coming round to tolerance of *We're going down the pub. **Do you want to come with**?* - and I'm not willing to spend another decade getting used to *Come on, all you malcontents! **Rise up and act against**!* That's a post-positioned preposition too far, for me.